# Can't add reference to System.Data.*

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

My c# solution had only one project at first where I had UI, Business, DAL in that project. I could use System.Data.SQLClientReader without problems. Now that I seperated it into 3 projects: (UI, Business, DAL) where Business and DAL are class libraries.

When I hover over for instance `SqlConnection` in the DAL and go to Quick fixes, I suddenly have to install it using NuGet. After doing this and visual studio not showing any errors in the background I start the program. I then receive this error in the Business layer calling a crud class in the DAL:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'`

Crud class:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace BornToMove.DAL {
    public class Crud {

        public Crud() { }

        public SqlDataReader Read(SqlCommand cmd) {
            return cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }

        public long Create(SqlCommand cmd) {
            return Convert.ToInt64(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        }
    }
}
```

DbMove class (only showing one method):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace BornToMove.DAL {
    public class DbMove : IDbMove {

        private Crud Crud { get; set; }

        public DbMove(Crud crud) {
            this.Crud = crud;
        }

        public Move GetMove(long id) {
            SqlConnection conn = null;
            try {
                conn = new MSSqlConn().GetConn();
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Move WHERE id=@id";
                SqlParameter idParam = new SqlParameter("@id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int) {
                    Value = id
                };
                cmd.Parameters.Add(idParam);
                cmd.Prepare();
                SqlDataReader reader = this.Crud.Read(cmd);
                Move move = null;
                if (reader.Read()) {
                    move = new Move {
                        Id = (long)reader.GetInt32(0),
                        MoveName = reader.GetString(1),
                        MoveDescription = reader.GetString(2),
                        Rating = reader.GetInt32(3),
                        SweatRate = reader.GetInt32(4)
                    };
                }
                return move;
            } catch {
                return null;
            } finally {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Why do I suddenly have to install it using NuGet? And why does this not even work?

Comment: Try to install the package also into ui project

Comment: Did you recompile the Nuget Code on your machine?  The Nuget code may of been compiled with a different version of Net which is causing the issue.  Make sure you do a clean build of the Nuget code.

Comment: Why would you need a nuget package for that? Just because there is a shiny button, does not mean pressing it is the best way to solve your problem.

Comment: @nvoigt My question exactly... like I mentioned in my post, I suddenly can only install it with NuGet now. There is no other option, and it doesn't even work. In the first project it just added a using directive and did not install anything

Comment: Well, again, a shiny button does not make it "the only solution". Can you reference it normally? Like add a dll reference? Without nuget, because it's part of the framework? If not, wat is the error or what does the screen look like?

Comment: @nvoigt And again, I understand that a shiny button is not the only solution. See my comment under @ Akshay Gaonkar 's answer and my own answer. When I referenced the dll nothing happened nothing get's recognized. (What is your problem o.O)

Comment: The main problem is that you did not say what you did to try something else. So you can reference the dll but there is no class recognized? Are you sure that your project is of the same Framework type as the former main project? Or did you by accident create a .NET Core or .NET Standard library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by making a new solution and instead of making the DAL and Business layers of type class library (.NET Standard) I used class library(.NET Framework). I was then able to reference the dll without any problems

Comment: +1000 if possible. Saved many hours of development time

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the version of `System.Data.SqlClient` dll in different projects. You should either use same verison in multiple projects or redirect to newer version by mentioning the [dependentAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/dependentassembly-element) in app.config

In your case the `System.Data.SqlClient` dll should e referenced only in DAL and removed from Business and UI because it is of no use there.

[image: System.Data.SqlClient namespace is available in Sytem.Data dll]

Comment: I only have a reference in DAL and there is only one version available to install. And I can only for as far as I've figured out install it using the NuGet package manager. Also I'm not really sure what to do with `dependentAssembley` or what to put inside the directives

Comment: Check if you really need to add reference from nuget package. System.Data.SqlClient namespace is available in System.Data dll. Just uninstall the nuget package and give refrence from System.Data dll

Comment: This also doesn't work, when I added reference to System.Data.dll It can't find SqlClient.

Comment: Microsoft has done some changes.. Just refer the article https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ec2361a3-1931-4423-bf68-08b206ce67aa/reference-systemdatasqlclient-not-found?forum=netfxbcl

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in an application which referenced a DLL I had built using the NuGet System.Data.SQLClient - unless the same NuGet package was also installed in the application there was an error as described above. Once I installed the NuGet SQLClient package in the application project all went perfectly.

I think your problem is that your Business layer, by calling the DAL, caused an error as the NuGet SQLClient package was not installed in either the business layer or the entire application project.

I hope that's useful,

Dermot